# Problems connecting to BitBucket with Cloud Build and Source Repositories

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-source-repos

I'm GCP project owner and trying to connect a BitBucket repo as mirror in *Cloud Source Repos*. Also have a *Cloud Build* trigger based on a BitBucket repo.

In *Cloud Source Repositories*, after granting access to my account, while configuring a mirror, no repositories from BitBucket appear and the following is displayed:

> The Bitbucket account [username] doesn't have access to any
>   Bitbucket repositories. You will need to grant this account permission
>   to repositories in Bitbucket before you can connect them.

In *Cloud Build* triggers, after the grant permissions dialog, *Select repository* lists no BitBucket repos and the *Continue* button is greyed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message will appear if your Bitbucket account only has Read or Write access to the repository you want to mirror. Check that you have Admin access on Bitbucket and try again. Also, make sure you're logged into the right Bitbucket account when attempting to make the connection.

Comment: Thanks - I already had write access. The fix was elevating to Admin level on the Bitbucket side. Can you make your comment reflect that for me to accept your answer?

Comment: Right, I tested it again and you're correct. I've amended the answer