# Error configuring Bitbucket/github as external repo in Google Cloud Source Repositories: "Failed to connect repositories"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitbucket

I've been trying to configure a repository I created on Bitbucket (BB) as an external repo on GCP with no success.

I get a new repo on BB, gave Admin permissions to the same user I used for GCP and log on with it on both sites using the same browser.

On GCP, "Connect external repository", I follow the steps in [1], I can see my BB account and the repos on GCP. I pick the right one, and as a final step, I press "Connect selected repository" and get "Connecting repository ..." for a while, but eventually "Failed to connect repositories". No further info

I read [2] but still no luck.

I suspect I might be missing something that must be done on BB side.

Any help? Thanks a lot

[1] https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-bitbucket-repository

[2] [Problems connecting to BitBucket with Cloud Build and Source Repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53515504/problems-connecting-to-bitbucket-with-cloud-build-and-source-repositories)

Comment: I've just checked with my Github account and got exactly the same error. Configuration on Github side of things seems ok: "Full control of private repositories"

Answer (score 41):

Rather than waiting 3 days for the GCP console to catch up, you can head over to
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sourcerepo.googleapis.com/overview and try to enable this API.

Once enabled, "Google Cloud Source" could connect to the repo straight away for me, and given the similar name / functionalities I would imagine it's just using "Source Repo" under the hood.

Comment: after enabling it, it actually worked. Thank you very much. I can't believe Google has this kind of weired bugs

Comment: best, i think GCP should show a message "Please enable xyz ", currently I am only get "cant connect ..."

Comment: Okay Google, wtf. This worked. I'm surprised on the lack of verbosity on the error... Thanks Dre!

Comment: This immediately resolved it. Didn't even have to refresh the page, just clicked connect again.

Comment: I can't believe this is still an issue 2 years later. This resolved my issue as well!

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours trying to find a solution, I just tried again 3 days later and it worked. I guess it takes a while to propagate newly created projects on GCP

BTW, after googling a lot for a solution, I found these pages pretty useful, but also bear in mind that you need to be logged on in both github/bitbucket and GCP for it to properly work (at least in my case):

https://fullstackgcp.com/developing-on-gcp-managing-source-codes-with-cloud-source-repositories-cjxhtj8b000251hs14zd58nil

https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-github-repository